# Restore symlink for Documents on Snow Leopard

Tags: linux, macos, macros, terminal, osx-snow-leopard

Problem: Restoring an alias to its original destination

In terminal it looks like this:

```
Documents -> /Users/[Username]/Documents
```

How do I change it to its original? Right now it's just an alias.

Comment: What do you mean "restore to original"? What kind of an original do you want to get?

Comment: I just want to remove this alias and replace it with the original location. Now it acts like an alias / symlink / shortcut. Before (yes, I did something stupid) it was the original Documents folder but now it's just an alias.

Comment: You mean you want to remove the link and create a directory instead of it?

Comment: The directory already exist (i.e., Documents) and is located in /Users/[Username]/Documents. I just want to remove the link and instead put the directory there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the task (from the discussion under the question):

```
The directory already exist (i.e., Documents) and is located
in /Users/[Username]/Documents. I just want to remove the link
and instead put the directory there
```

you need to do following:

```
$ rm Documents
$ mv /Users/[Username]/Documents .
```

But check first that you really remove link:

```
$ ls -ld Documents
```

The first letter of the string in the output must be `l` (for symbolic link).